# Creating csr for SSL request on Ubuntu gives error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I am trying to create SSL certification on my website. To, create csr , I used the command:

```
openssl req –new –newkey rsa:2048 –nodes –keyout mydomain.key –out mydomain.csr
```

But,I get the error saying:

> req: Use -help for summary.

I checked if **openssl** is installed or not, and it gives the version. So, it is installed.

I don't know what to do. I am fairly new to this. This is my first try to get the SSL.

I am having hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate and sign the private key for `my.domain.com` using `openssl`.

Create a new encrypted private key.

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out /etc/pki/tls/private/httpdkey.pem
```

Enter httpd at the passphrase prompt (or just press empty).
Generate a self-signed certificate using the key.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key /etc/pki/tls/private/httpdkey.pem -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/httpdcert.pem -days 365
```

OR

- Generate a certificate signing request to be sent to a certificate authority:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key {{filename.key}} -out {{filename.csr}}
```

- Generate a self-signed certificate from a certificate signing request valid for some number of days:

```
openssl x509 -req -days {{days}} -in {{filename.csr}} -signkey {{filename.key}} -out {{filename.crt}}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit

Comment: Yeah sure, what exactly you is not clear? :)

Comment: Will it provide me csr file and key too?

Comment: The first is Certificate Signing Request (CSR). This defines the information which will be contained within the certificate and includes things such as the organization name and domain name. The CSR is then sent to a CA or used to generate a self-signed certificate.
We can easily generate the CSR and then the private key and public certificate with one command. For example, here's how to generate a CSR with a 2048 bit key and 600 day expiry:
```openssl req -x509 -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -out public.pem -days 600```

Comment: This example will ask a series of questions for the CSR and then automatically generate the private key (private.key) and the public certificate (public.pem)

Comment: ok.. I ll check

Comment: As far as I understood you needed to add cryptographic standard into your command.

Comment: Yeah... It worked. Also, I followed the [link](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/generating-certificate-signing-request-csr-ubuntu-16-04/)

Answer (score 14):

I was seeing the exact same behaviour trying to generate a CSR in Ubuntu based on the instructions i found on the digicert website. After searching around online forever I finally noticed that two of the hyphens in my command looked slightly different.

It looks like [the instructions I copied](https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/ubuntu-server-with-apache2-openssl.htm) actually contained some en dashes instead of hyphens.

When I manually typed out the command instead of copying/pasting the openssl command worked as expected

Copy/pasted Digicert command:

```
openssl req –new –newkey rsa:2048 –nodes –keyout ./server.key –out ./server.csr
```

[Screenshot of failed command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJsl6.png)

Manually typed Digicert command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ./server.key -out ./server.csr
```

[Screenshot of successful command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSRPY.png)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.

Comment: Good catch ;) Indeed the Digicert page that comes first when googling the relevant keywords uses dashes instead of hyphens...

Answer (score -1):

I have spend few hours on this issue. In my case the problem was connected with dashes. I have copied and used this string from one site `openssl req –new –newkey rsa:2048 –nodes –keyout dreamlist.key –out dreamlist.csr` and it throwed `req: Use -help for summary.` issue. I have replaced all `–`s(from command) with `-`(write by keyboard) and now it works just fine.

The problem is that in some sites they use special characters in commands which looks really similar to dashes, but that characters doesn't work in terminal.